# How change Gateway of subnet ( private network, Internal) on MAAS

Tags: 16.04, maas, nat, gateway

Ubuntu : 16.04

MAAS: 2.0.0 beta 3


I need to change the gateway address of my subnet( private lAN,Internal which is 192.168.120.1) to ip address of my region/rack controller( internal ip 192.168.120.2)

The reason behind this I am using NAT on my region/rack controller and all nodes must have gateway as 192.168.120.2 to connect to internet for download required files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that using MAAS CLI.

Login to your MAAS server via SSH. Get API key from your administrator account (take a look to the top right corner in the web GUI) and run the following command:

```
maas login my-mass http://localhost/MAAS
```

Find ID of a subnet you need to change:

```
maas my-mass subnets read
```

Change it:

```
maas my-maas subnet update <ID> gateway_ip=192.168.120.2
```

Please note, I have not tried running commands above, so there might be typos, but when in need, just use `--help`:

```
maas my-maas subnet update --help
```